# Returning a list of lists from a webservice

Tags: .net, web-services

Can I have a webservice method that returns `List<List<MyObject>>` in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<List<MyObject>> ServiceOperation();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public List<List<MyObject>> ServiceOperation()
    {
        return new List<List<MyObject>>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can.  You can return pretty much any object.  And I've done exactly this in several projects.